# Not able to Print more than one page of content rendered by React

Tags: html, css, typescript, dom

I have a react component (`className={"print-table"}`) which renders multi page content.
The rendering and scrolling works fine in browsers.

However when I try to print it using right click print in browser, the preview shows only one page, with no scrolling in the preview. My css has following for the component:

```
 @media print {
    body * {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .print-table, .print-table * {
        visibility: visible;
    }

    .print-table {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions in fixing this will be greatly helpful

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to change it to `@media screen  {` to see what the print version would look like. All the content you want for the print-job is probably not in the DOM.

Comment: @Kunukn The DOM seems to have the content as changing format to A3 or A0 displays all the content.

Comment: I am speculating: If all the content is in the DOM and shows only one page, then I would look for possible `overflow: hidden`, or maybe try setting `position: relative;`